# How do I change my float into a two decimal number with a comma as a decimal point separator in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

I have a float: 1.2333333

How do I change it into a two decimal number with a comma as a decimal point separator, eg 1,23?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316238/python-float-to-decimal-conversion

Comment: @Ólafur Waage - the locale stuff is not in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316238/python-float-to-decimal-conversion

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get two decimals, use

```
'%.2f' % 1.2333333
```

To get a comma, use `replace()`:

```
('%.2f' % 1.2333333).replace('.', ',')
```

A second option would be to [change the locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) to some place which uses a comma and then use `locale.format()`:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'FR')
locale.format('%.2f', 1.2333333)
```

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. the normal `"%f"` string formatter is not locale-dependent.

Comment: Sometimes, it is: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18994  I've improved my answer to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: @FlorianPilz: Not with my version of Python and not [according to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Comment: @AaronDigulla I removed my comment, since I explained the behavior in Ruby. Sadly I cannot change my vote.

Answer (score 8):

The [locale module](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) can help you with reading and writing numbers in the locale's format.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
'sv_SE.UTF-8'
>>> locale.format("%f", 2.2)
'2,200000'
>>> locale.format("%g", 2.2)
'2,2'
>>> locale.atof("3,1415926")
3.1415926000000001
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mess with the locale, you can of course do the formatting yourself. This might serve as a starting point:

```
def formatFloat(value, decimals = 2, sep = ","):
  return "%s%s%0*u" % (int(value), sep, decimals, (10 ** decimals) * (value - int(value)))
```

Note that this will always truncate the fraction part (i.e. 1.04999 will print as 1,04).