# Python Pandas Changing Column String Values to Float values in a new column

Tags: python, string, pandas, floating-point, type-conversion

I have a dataframe which contains a column of strings of float values (negative and positive float values) in the format 
.000  (3dp). This number is represented as a string in Column1 and I would like to add a column2 to the DataFrame as a float and convert the string representation of the float value to a float value preserving the 3 dp. I have had problems trying to do this and have error message of "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" Grateful for any help

Code

```
dataframe4['column2'] = ''
dataframe4['column2']=dataframe4['column1'].astype('float64')

#Round column1, column2 float columns to 3 decimal places

dataframe4.round({'column1': 3, 'column2': 3})
```

Comment: if column 1 contains string it would give error when round it.

Comment: Thanks Tawab. I was wondering how to do type conversion of string to float in pandas

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I totally understood your question but you can try

```
dataframe4['column2'] = dataframe4['column1'].apply(lambda x : float(x))
```

Edit : If there are some numbers with commas, you can try:

```
dataframe4['column2'] = dataframe4['column1'].apply(lambda x : float(x.replace(",","")))
```

Comment: Hi GatienC. Unfortunately I tried the above and got an error message when trying to convert string to float. ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9,826.000'

Comment: @daveb can you confirm that you have a comma in these numbers? That would break your conversion

Comment: Hi Patrick, Many thanks, unfortunately there is commas in the string representation of the float number. Would it be possible to add them back in if I remove them before the conversion?

Comment: yes that should def work. Let me look at it real quick

Comment: edited my answer with a .replace , it should work (didn't see ur precedent comment, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you have commas in your floats, e.g. '9,826.000'

You can fix like below

```
import re
re.sub(r",", "", "1,1000.20")
# returns '11000.20' and the below works
float(re.sub(r",", "", "1,1000.20"))
# you can e.g. use apply to apply to all your numbers in the DataFrame
df["new_col"] = df["old_col"].apply(lambda x: float(re.sub(r",", "", x)))
```

To still show the resulting float with commas afterwards in pandas, you can change the display setting for float as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102734/format-a-number-to-commas-to-separate-thousands-in-python)

IDK how you want to output these, but e.g. in the `to_excel` function, you can specify a float format, cf [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) or re-format the column before output, similar to the above. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530430/how-do-i-change-my-float-into-a-two-decimal-number-with-a-comma-as-a-decimal-poi) for some ideas.