# Django max aggregate comparison issue

Tags: python, django

I'm confused as to what's going on with comparing a Decimal value to the value from a Django Max aggregate queryset.  The comparison is returning false when I expect it to be true, and I can't figure out why.

I get the queryset like:

```
prev_hourly_rate = PayRate.objects.filter(employee__exact=emp_pk).exclude(pk=pay_rate_id).aggregate(Max('hourlyRate'))
```

That returns

```
 {'hourlyRate__max': Decimal('25.1234')}
```

I want to compare that Decimal value to another Decimal value, 25.1234 (represented by the variable hr), but that's returning False.  I'm doing the comparison like:

```
if prev_hourly_rate['hourlyRate__max'] == hr:
```

or

```
if prev_hourly_rate['hourlyRate__max'] == Decimal(hr):
```

or even

```
if prev_hourly_rate['hourlyRate__max'] == Decimal.from_float(hr):
```

and it always returns False.  I obviously am missing something really simple. Please point out to my tired brain what it is.  Thanks.

Comment: What is `hr`? If it's a float, chances are it's not exactly equivalent to 25.1234. Try printing the result of `Decimal(hr)` to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316238/python-float-to-decimal-conversion) for more information, but the short version is that `Decimal(hr) == Decimal('25.123400000000000176214598468504846096038818359375')`

In order to create a Decimal with the exact value you want, you have to use the string representation of the float. `prev_hourly_rate['hourlyRate__max'] == Decimal(repr(hr))` should get you what you want.

Comment: Indeed, that's what's going on.  All decimals are not created equal, apparently.  I also tried converting both values to float, and that also worked, but I like this solution best.  Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly correct; Decimals are created by passing either a string or a float. Because Decimals use different precision logic than floats, passing a float will cause unexpected behavior.