# pandas : astype(float) not converting string to float type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe column `price` which has a value like `$783024.20`...
This is a string with datatype as object..

```
test =
 0.  price
 1. '$783024.20'

dtype = object


    test['price'].astype(float)
```

getting an error:

> could not convert string to float: '$783024.20'

what can I do for this, as I thought this would work?

Comment: Why should it work?  `float('$1.23')` doesn't work.

Comment: There is no reason `str` can be cast to `float` just because `$` should mean "dollar". In any case, there is already a thread about pandas and currency in SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535163/what-dtype-to-use-for-money-representation-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: for your problem you can simply do `df.price.astype(str).str.replace("$", "").astype(float)` and it should work

Comment: I've been trying to remove dollar sign but it wasn't reading it.. Thanks for the answers.. Thanks @ClementWalter.. :)

Comment: Have you tried test['price'].str.slice(start=1).astype(float) or test['price'].str.extract(r'\$(\d*\.\d*)').astype(float)? You might have to play around with the regex a bit depending on what's in your column.