# Floating Point Limitations

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

My code:

```
a = '2.3'
```

I wanted to display `a` as a floating point value.

Since `a` is a string, I tried:

```
float(a)
```

The result I got was :

```
2.2999999999999998
```

I want a solution for this problem. Please, kindly help me.

I was following [this tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: @rejinacm.myopenid.com: you might want to remove the comment "This is a drawback of Python." !

Comment: -1 to the freaks who downvoted this question instead of fixing it!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286061/python-decimal-place-issues-with-floats, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286061/python-decimal-place-issues-with-floats

Answer (score 19):

I think it reflects more on your understanding of floating point types than on Python. See [my article about floating point numbers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) (.NET-based, but still relevant) for the reasons behind this "inaccuracy". If you need to keep the exact decimal representation, you should use the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Comment: decimal returns a string.I want a float type only.

Comment: @rejinacm - float types are not exact, your paper actually explains this at the end and explains why this happens.

Comment: Decimal doesn't "return" a string - you *can* convert it to a string, but a decimal value is just a value, which you can manipulate separately etc. If you really need float for whatever reason, you need to accept that you're not going to be able to represent 2.3 exactly in it.

Comment: @rejinacm: How about you read the page that I linked to? It gives lots of examples, including division.

Comment: In addition to Jon's article, I also recommend reading What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic. A copy is available on http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a drawback of python, rather, it is a drawback of the way floating point numbers are stored on a computer. Regardless of implementation language, you will find similar problems.

You say that you want to 'display' A as a floating point, why not just display the string? Visually it will be identical to what you expect.

As Jon mentioned, if your needs are more than just 'displaying' the floating point number, you should use the decimal module to store the exact representation.

Answer (score 5):

Excellent answers explaining reasons. I just wish to add a possible practical solution from the standard library:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = Decimal('2.3')
>>> print a
2.3
```

This is actually a (very) F.A.Q. for Python and you can [read the answer here](http://www.python.org/doc/faq/general/#why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate).

---

Edit: I just noticed that John Skeet already mentioned this. Oh well...

Comment: Not sure how is the link related?