# Python float numbers representation

Tags: python, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating Point Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406361/floating-point-limitations)

Hi there,

maybe this has a very simple answer. I was playing around with the Python interpreter.

```
>>> 1
1
>>> 1.1
1.1000000000000001
>>> 1.2
1.2
```

Why `1.1` was interpreted as `1.1000000000000001`?

Comment: because you still did not switch to  python 3

Comment: Please search.  Questions of floating point are common.  Perhaps every week someone asks this question.  For example, all of these are the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+floating-point.

Answer (score 1):

From [The Floating-Point Guide:](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

> **Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and
>   instead I get a weird result like
>   0.30000000000000004?**
>
> Because internally, computers use a
>   format (binary floating-point) that
>   cannot accurately represent a number
>   like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or
>   interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that
>   format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the
>   calculation happens.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the way the numbers are stored internally. The format is specified in the [IEEE_754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) speficiation.

Some more information can be found on single precision floats [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision)

Answer (score 0):

you can look at [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for Floating Point Arithmetic Issues and Limitations

In any case in python 3 you have:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> 1.1
1.1
>>> 1.2
1.2
>>>
```