# Python Shell - "Extras" in float subtraction

Tags: python, shell, floating-point, subtraction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating Point Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406361/floating-point-limitations)

Using Python 2.7 here.

Can someone explain why this happens in the shell?

```
>>> 5.2-5.0
0.20000000000000018
```

Searching yielded things about different scales of numbers not producing the right results (a very small number and a very large number), but that seemed pretty general, and considering the numbers I'm using are of the same scale, I don't think that's why this happens.

EDIT: I suppose I didn't define that the "this thing happening" I meant was that it returns 0.2 ... 018 instead of simply resulting in 0.2. I get that print rounds, and removed the print part in the code snippet, as that was misleading.

Comment: There are really three parts to this question: "Why is `5.2 - 5.0 != 0.2`", "Why does evaluating the expression not do the same as printing it", and "Why/how are the repr and str different"? My answer focuses on part 1, Ashwini Chaudhary's is a perfect answer to part 2, and Martijn Pieters's nicely handles part 3.

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html . It's a much gentler introduction to the issues than the Goldberg paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to understand that 5.2-5.0 really is 0.20000000000000018, not 0.2. The standard explanation for this is found in [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

If you don't want to read all of that, just accept that 5.2, 5.0, and 0.20000000000000018 are all just approximations, as close as the computer can get to the numbers you really way.

Python has some tricks to allow you to not know what every computer scientist should know and still get away with it. The main trick is that `str(f)`—that is, the human-readable rendition of a floating-point number—is truncated to 12 significant digits, so `str(5.2-5.0)` is `"0.2"`, not `"0.20000000000000018"`. But sometimes you need all the precision you can get, so `repr(f)`—that is, the machine-readable rendition—is not truncated, so `repr(5.2-5.0)` is `"0.20000000000000018"`.

Now the only thing left to understand is what the interpreter shell does. As Ashwini Chaudhary explains, just evaluating something in the shell prints out its `repr`, while the `print` statement prints out its `str`.

Answer (score 2):

shell uses `repr()`:

```
In [1]: print repr(5.2-5.0)
0.20000000000000018

In [2]: print str(5.2-5.0)
0.2

In [3]: print 5.2-5.0
0.2
```

Comment: I apologize, I didn't make my question very clear. I want to know why 5.2-5.0 doesn't simply result in 0.2?

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of `float.__str__` limits the output to 12 digits only.

Thus, the least significant digits are dropped and what is left is the value 0.2.

To print more digits (if available), use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
print '%f' % result  # prints 0.200000
```

That defaults to 6 digits, but you can specify more precision:

```
print '%.16f' % result  # prints 0.2000000000000002
```

Alternatively, python offers a newer [string formatting method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) too:

```
print '{0:.16f}'.format(result)  # prints 0.2000000000000002
```

Why python produces the 'imprecise' result in the first place has everything to do with the imprecise nature of [floating point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/). Use the [`decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) instead if you need more predictable precision:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 1
>>> Decimal(5.2) - Decimal(5.0)
Decimal('0.2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has two different ways of converting an object to a string, the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods. `__str__` is meant to be a normal string output and is used by `print`; `__repr__` is meant to be a more exact representation and is what is displayed when you don't use `print`, or when you print the contents of a list or dictionary.  `__str__` rounds floating-point values.

As for why the actual result of the subtraction is 0.20000000000000018 rather than 0.2 exactly, it has to do with the internal representation of floating point. It's impossible to represent 5.2 exactly because it's an infinitely repeating binary number. The closest that you can come is approximately 5.20000000000000018.