# Difference between two identical NSTimeInterval is different than zero

Tags: ios, swift, double, precision, difference

**Edit**:

This is not strictly a Floating point question as NSTimeInterval is derived from Double. However I added Floating point to the tags as it could be related.

**Problem:**

When computing the difference between two identical NSTimeInterval I get a value **different than zero** (-0.0000013etc..).

**Question:**

Why is that? My understanding is that they are Double values so the behaviour should be consistent (if those where Float type it would be different).

**Swift Code:**

```
let timeDifference : NSTimeInterval = timeValue.timeIntervalSince1970 - timeStarted!.timeIntervalSince1970
```

Comment: is `timeStarted === timeValue` ? how were they created ? how do you know they're exactly equal ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating Point Limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406361/floating-point-limitations).  To be clear, a `Double` (or `NSTimeInterval`, which is a typealias for `Double`) still has all of the same limitations as a `Float`.  They're all floating point numbers.  Doubles simply have double the accuracy.

Comment: @nhgrif: Very unlikely. If the dates _were_ identical then this difference would definitely be zero.

Comment: The two values are created using NSDate() and they are identical when I look at the debugger (same date, same hour, same minute, same seconds).

Comment: If you used `NSDate()` two times in a row, it generated two slightly different dates (a few nanoseconds off).

Comment: You can't create two identical date objects using `NSDate`'s zero-argument constructor.  Please add the code where you're constructing the date objects.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. If you create a date, ```[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]``` and put that into an NSTimeInterval variable. Calculations on it will return non-zero values. I've tried subtracting whole numbers from this variable and get precision errors that mess up calculations expecting a zero number.