# DecimalField won't accept a float

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
Model(models.Model)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

and I have a string:

```
new_price = "39.99"
```

When I try the following:

```
model_instance.price = float(new_price)
model_instance.save()
```

I get `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'price': ['Ensure that there are no more than 10 digits in total.']}`

Why?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I tried that and get the same error unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has to do with [Python's internal `float` representation's limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406361/floating-point-limitations). But you can use the string directly with a `DecimalField`:

```
model_instance.price = "39.99"
model_instance.save()
```

If you have dynamic input you can use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) directly to get the required precision:

```
from decimal import *

model_instance.price = Decimal(new_price).quantize(
    Decimal('0.01'), 
    rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Comment: That's what I tried the first time but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Actually, specifying `model_instance.price = str(new_price)` did the trick, weird though as it was already a string! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using decimal.Decimal instead of float()