# Why does indexing this Numpy matrix cause an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I'm using:

- Python 3.5.4
- Numpy 1.16.2

Given the code:

```
import numpy as np
num = 3
a = np.asmatrix(np.eye(num, num))
b = np.asmatrix(range(0, num))
print(a[b].transpose())
```

I get the result:

```
[[1.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
 [1.77658241e-307 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]
 [3.47328271e-310 0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000]]
```

But by either changing the definition of b to `np.asarray(...)`, or by performing a second indexing to get the first item in the list (`print(a[b][0].transpose()`) I get the expected result:

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

What is going on? I've not experienced this bug before don't have a clue to the underlying cause. If its something fundamental to Python (I'm quite new to it still) I'd quite like to learn about it so that I don't sink quite as much time into debugging it as I have this time. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not an error. Basically you see a representation of integer into float (decimal form) and it is not exactly the same with integer value. See similar post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286061/decimal-place-issues-with-floats-and-decimal-decimal

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ If that were the case I'd expect it to produce the same error irrespective of how I manipulated it before hand. In both cases, without the transpose, there are no rounding errors and I get the identity matrix back with only 1.0 and 0.0 values showing.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy `matrix` objects try to ensure they're always 2D, but they don't quite do a complete job of it.

When you do

```
b = np.asmatrix(range(0, num))
```

`range(0, num)` is a 1D sequence, but `asmatrix` creates a single-row 2D matrix instead of a 1D object. `asarray` would produce a 1D array.

When you do

```
a[b]
```

this is a fancy indexing operation that produces a *3D* matrix. `numpy.matrix` objects are never supposed to be 3D, and the following `transpose` doesn't know how to handle that, producing nonsensical results. Particularly, the strange, almost-0 numbers in the output are **not** due to rounding error; they're due to the nonsensical strides of the resulting matrix, which cause unaligned memory access and try to read fragments of separate floats as a single float:

```
In [13]: a[b].transpose().strides
Out[13]: (1, 24)
```

That's a 1-byte stride in the first dimension.

---

The key takeaway here: don't use `numpy.matrix`.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Wonder why there isn't an error message / warning appearing to indicate as much. Took me ages to figure out it was that code messing things up.

Comment: I presume you mean "don't use `numpy.matrix` for indexing"?

Comment: @user3303504: Don't use it at all if you have any other option. It causes all kinds of problems, not just this problem, and the only benefit it ever had is gone with the introduction of the `@` operator.

Comment: Also see the warning in its [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html): "It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future."

Comment: @user3303504, in your case it's the fact that `a` is `np.matrix` and `b` is 2d (matrix or array) that produces the false 3d `matrix`.