# Sum diff problem/bug in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, floating-point

I have this XML data and try and make a sum of it using the XSLT snippet below.

**Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<values>
    <value>159.14</value>
    <value>-2572.50</value>
    <value>-2572.50</value>
    <value>2572.50</value>
    <value>2572.50</value>
    <value>-159.14</value>
</values>
```

**Xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(values/value)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In my world the value should then be **0** but it ends up being **-0.0000000000005684341886080801**

Run it in Visual Studio and see for yourself. ***Why?*** is this happening?

Comment: Just to add a little completeness to the solution given below below and answer your question of "Why?" Check out "What Every Computer Scientist should know about Floating-Point Arithmetic" http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems your XSLT processor convert <strike>decimal numbers</strike> strings to float-point precision numbers before sum;

Well, you can always to use round function and divide by your desired precision or to use format-number function, if available:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="round(sum(values/value)) div 100"/><br />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(values/value), '0.00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Riri: If you are surprised about this behavior, I think this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error and the linked page in the accepted answer is worth a read.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(values/value),'0.00')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding round?

```
round(sum(values/value))
```

Comment: Posted the same comment above, but it feels in place here as well. Just to add a little completeness to the solution given below below and answer your question of "Why?" Check out "What Every Computer Scientist should know about Floating-Point Arithmetic" http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg%5Fgoldberg.html