# Why is Lua arithmetic is not equal to itself?

Tags: lua, floating-point, point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a simple example of floating point/rounding error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error)

When I execute the following Lua code:

```
a = 5.6
b = 14 * 0.4
c = 11.2 / 2
d = 28 * 0.2
print( a == b )
print( a == c )
print( a == d )
print( b == c )
print( b == d )
print( c == d )
```

I get the following results:

```
false
true
false
false
true
false
```

Can someone explain why 14 * 0.4 and 28 * 0.2 are not equal to 5.6?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are dealing with the natural imprecision of binary floating point numbers. Your number `a` might be 5.5999999999999996 and your result `b` might be 5.6000000000000005, which are not equal.

In fact, here is the same calculation as done by Python:

```
>>> 5.6
5.5999999999999996
>>> 14 * 0.4
5.6000000000000005
```

This behaviour is common to all implementations of binary floating point numbers.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the explaination. Appreciate it.