# if lua number is double, does =/<=/>= operations always correct?

Tags: lua, floating-point

As you know, float point has a precision problem, that is a value 1 will be 0.9999999. And lua use == in C to check whether two double numbers equal. So the problem is:

```
a = 5.6
b = 14 * 0.4
print(a==b) ; => false
```

But the worse thing is:

```
a = 1
...
if a < 1 then print("<1") end ; => sometimes a < 1
```

So how can i avoid this ? I check out lua source code, it seems i can modify luai_numeq/luai_numle) macros in luaconf.h, but is this necessary ?

**update**

The second example is not really correct. Actually my problem is, I pass a value 1 to c/c++ which use lua_tonumber to get the value, and i store this value in a double variable, and after sometime, I push the value (lua_pushnumber) to lua, and a < 1 happened:

```
in lua:
my_cfunction(1)
...
in c:
int my_cfunction(lua_State *L) {
    double val = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
    ...
...
lua_pushnumber(L, val);

in lua:
local a = my_cfunction2()
if a < 1 then ... end
```

Comment: This is a "problem" with all floating point math when you convert to a different radix (i.e. base2 to base10). Get used to it. Program around it. Definitely do NOT hack the language source. For one, you'll have non-portable code. Don't know what's up with example 2. What does ... represent? I think your case extremely unlikely... I wouldn't touch Lua with a bargepole if 1 < 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366954/why-is-lua-arithmetic-is-not-equal-to-itself

Comment: I suspect you did something wrong; arithmetic on integer values in Lua that doesn't overflow should always be precise (although Lua uses a C "double" type, IEEE floating-point is precise when operating on integer values that don't overflow).  If you really have a test-case that you think shows otherwise, please include the _complete_ test-case; code snippets aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> float point has a precision problem

[It doesn't.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FloatingPoint)

A 64 bit double can hold many more integer values precisely than a 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 5):

> As you know, float point has a precision problem, that is a value 1 will be 0.9999999

I don't know that at all. Because it's not true. 1.0 is 1.0. This:

```
a = 1
if a < 1 then print("<1") end
```

Will *never* print "<1". Not unless you actually change `a`. Even this:

```
a = 2
a = a - 1
if a < 1 then print("<1") end
```

Will likewise never hit the `print` statement.

As long as you are performing integer arithmetic on Lua's numbers, you will end up with integers. No addition, subtraction, or multiplication of integer values will leave you with a non-integer number value.