# How safe is comparing numbers in lua with equality operator?

Tags: lua, numbers, double, equality

In my engine I have a Lua VM for scripting. In the scripts, I write things like:

```
stage = stage + 1
if (stage == 5) then ... end
```

and

```
objnum = tonumber("5")
if (stage == objnum)
```

According to the Lua sources, Lua uses a simple equality operator when comparing doubles, the internal number type it uses.

I am aware of precision problems when dealing with floating point values, so I want to know if the comparison is safe, that is, will there be any problems with simply comparing these numbers using Lua's default '==' operation? If so, are there any countermeasures I can employ to make sure 1+2 always compares as equal to 3? Will converting the values to strings work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [if lua number is double, does =/<=/>= operations always correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526615/if-lua-number-is-double-does-operations-always-correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can employ to make sure 1+2 always compares as equal to 3?

[You needn't worry.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FloatingPoint) The number type in Lua is `double`, which can hold many more integers exactly than a `long int`.

Comment: So am I guaranteed that the operation n+m==q will always be true for doubles (where n,m and q are integer values, and q < 100)?

Comment: Yes, where q < 4503599627370496 (i.e. 4.5 quadrillion).

Comment: And will the `tonumber("5")` call give me a value that can safely be used in integer arithmetic?

Comment: To the extent that `strtod` does. So, yes.

Answer (score 14):

You *may* be better off by converting to string and then comparing the results if you only care about equality in some cases. For example:

```
> print(21, 0.07*300, 21 == 0.07*300, tostring(21) == tostring(0.07*300))
21      21      false   true
```

I learned this hard way when I gave my students an assignment with these numbers (0.07 and 300) and asked them to implement a unit test that then miserably failed complaining that 21 is not equal 21 (it was comparing actual numbers, but displaying stringified values). It was a good reason for us to have a discussion about comparing floating point values.

Comment: this example is why it is a very good reason to use math.floor() on calculated values where precision may be an issue and isn't important.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison and basic operations on doubles is safe in certain situations. In particular if the numbers and their result can be expressed exactly - including all low value integers.

So `2+1 == 3` will be fine for doubles.

NOTE: I believe there's even some guarantees for certain math functions ( like `pow` and `sqrt` ) and if your compiler/library respects those then `sqrt(4.0)==2.0` or `4.0 == pow(2.0,2.0)` will reliably be true.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Lua is compiled with c++ floats, and behind the scenes number comparisons boils down to float comparisons in c/c++, which are indeed problematic and discussed in several threads, e.g. [most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison).

Lua makes the situation only slightly worse by converting all numbers, including c++ integers, into floats. So you need to keep it in mind.