# Lua float errors

Tags: lua, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm fairly new to lua, but I read that it does not have integers, so all numbers are floats.
I noticed in my log that some numbers get a slight inaccuracy added to it. For instance 0.14 is written as 0.14000000059605.
In that function it doesn't really matter if the number is a little diferent, as it is a comparison with a random number. But I do a lot of equals comparisons with numbes like NumReg() == 2 where it would give a wrong result if the 2 gets unrounded.
Do do I have to account for this by rounding them down, or are non-tiny numbers not affected?

Comment: See https://0.30000000000000004.com/ for an explanation of why that happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How safe is comparing numbers in lua with equality operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316769/how-safe-is-comparing-numbers-in-lua-with-equality-operator)

Comment: If you're only doing integer arithmetic up to 2^52, there will most likely be no rounding errors (exceptions to this might be something like `sqrt` or `pow`, but the builtin arithmetic operators should otherwise be fine). You can usually safely use exact comparisons there.

If you're doing computations on actual floating point numbers though, consider comparing with a small bias: `math.abs(x - expected) < 1e-6` for example.

Comment: Lua 5.3+ does have integers, typically 64-bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I figured this was something that has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer because most of the terms are new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can format a float for your needs.
Example to play with in an interactive Lua console...

```
> _VERSION
Lua 5.4
tonumber(string.format('%.3f', 0.14000000059605))
0.14
> print(tonumber(string.format('%.3f', 0.14000000059605)))
0.14
> type(tonumber(string.format('%.3f', 0.14000000059605)))
number
> math.type(tonumber(string.format('%.3f', 0.14000000059605)))
float
> tonumber(string.format('%.3f', 0.14000000059605)) == 0.140
true
```