# LUA (Corona SDK) math.floor() return wrong value with increment of 0.1

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a strange bug when i use **Math.floor** function on double values incremented of **0.1** each time.

It happens only with an increment of 0.1 and start at value 5

Exemple : math.floor(4) return **4** but math.floor(5) return **4** !!!

You can try it yourself, with this simple piece of code :

```
for i=3,7,0.1 do 
    print("val : "..i.." floor : "..math.floor(i))
end
```

Here is the result of the above code :

```
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3.1 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3.2 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3.3 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3.4 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3.5 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3.6 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3.7 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3.8 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 3.9 floor : 3
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4.1 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4.2 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4.3 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4.4 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4.5 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4.6 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4.7 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4.8 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 4.9 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5 floor : 4
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5.1 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5.2 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5.3 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5.4 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5.5 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5.6 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5.7 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5.8 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 5.9 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6 floor : 5
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6.1 floor : 6
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6.2 floor : 6
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6.3 floor : 6
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6.4 floor : 6
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6.5 floor : 6
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6.6 floor : 6
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6.7 floor : 6
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6.8 floor : 6
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 6.9 floor : 6
 Corona Simulator[1494:707] val : 7 floor : 6
```

If it can help, if we applied a **modulo 1** on the result of a buggy value, we get this as result : **0.99999999999999**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Lua arithmetic is not equal to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366954/why-is-lua-arithmetic-is-not-equal-to-itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

indeed it's a common float problem,

Here is the official response i've received from corona support :

> Hello,
>
> What you are seeing is a general problem with floating point numbers.
>   All numbers in Lua are floating point numbers and as such are subject
>   to rounding errors. Adding 0.1 to another floating point number is not
>   exactly 0.1 and the error accumulative when used over and over again.
>   When you think the number is 5.0, it may be 4.99999999999999999, so
>   floor returns 4. The print statement may be rounding up before
>   printing.
>
> The math library is standard Lua code (v5.1) and has not been modified
>   for Corona.
>
> You can google the subject or floating point rounding problems, but in
>   general you need to be careful when using floating point math.
>
> Regards, Tom
>
> -- Corona Labs - Support support@coronalabs.com

Answer (score 4):

Floating point numbers are devilish.  Don't use them as loop counters.

```
for i = 30, 70 do 
    local i = i / 10
    print("val : "..i.." floor : "..math.floor(i))
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works this way, but the thing is i don't use a for loop in my real project.

I use a simple addition (to update a character position). 

I've tried to replace each float in my code with calculated values (such as 1/10) and it still dont work :(

Comment: @user1029976 - You can use rounding to nearest n/10 : `x = math.floor(x*10+0.5)/10`

Comment: @user1029976 the underlying problem is that 0.1 (or 1/10) is not a finite binary number (it's `0.0001100110011...`). The floating-point representation has to cap that at some point which is why you get rounding errors at some point. Increment your character position by 1 instead, and divide it by 10 only when you actually use the value.