# Error with EXPECT_EQ for sum of double or float

Tags: c++, unit-testing, floating-point, googletest

I am unable to understand why the test case failed in case of summing double numbers or floats. It works very finely for the integer data type.

//the method in simple_method.h

```
double sum ( double a, double b)
{
    double res = a+b;
    return res;
}
```

// the test case for this method

```
TEST(simpleSum, sumOfFloat)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(4.56, sum(0.56, 4.0));
}
```

// the output is

```
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from simpleSum
[ RUN      ] simpleSum.sumOfFloat
/home/pcadmin/Desktop/so/so3/simple_method_test.cpp:7: Failure
Value of: sum(0.56, 4.0)
  Actual: 4.56
Expected: 4.56
[  FAILED  ] simpleSum.sumOfFloat (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from simpleSum (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] simpleSum.sumOfFloat

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use [`EXPECT_NEAR`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/reference/assertions.md#expect_near-expect_near) or the [`DoubleEq`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/reference/assertions.md#expect_double_eq-expect_double_eq) matcher instead. Floating point operations can lead to [rounding errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error) which makes the results ever so slightly different.

Comment: `EXPECT_NEAR` has a broken link. I was able to find this part of documentation instead: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#floating-point-macros

Comment: I refrained as I didn't know if you could get the original link working

Comment: For me only `EXPECT_NEAR` worked. Even when the difference was less than `10^(-5)` ``EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ` failed

Answer (score 41):

See documentation for [Floating Point Comparison](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#floating-point-comparison)

[`EXPECT_EQ`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_EQ) uses exact match.
But you cannot match two floating numbers exactly. (at least with ease.)

You can use [`EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ` or `EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ). (with heuristic bounds)
Also, you may use [`EXPECT_NEAR`](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_NEAR) with specific bounds.

Answer (score 6):

From https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/10/tott-floating-point-comparison.html

> When comparing floating-point values, checking for equality might lead
>   to unexpected results. Rounding errors can lead to a result that is
>   close to the expected one, but not equal. As a consequence, an
>   assertion might fail when checking for equality of two floating-point
>   quantities even if the program is implemented correctly.
>
> The Google C++
>   Testing Framework provides functions for comparing two floating-point
>   quantities up to a given precision.

```
ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(expected, actual);
ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ(expected, actual);

EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(expected, actual);
EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(expected, actual);
```

In your case,

```
TEST(simpleSum, sumOfFloat)
{
    EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(4.56, sum(0.56, 4.0));
}
```

Comment: the thing I don't like about EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ() is that you cannot provide an error delta. Sometimes a test will still fail because of floating point error, esp accumulated error.

Comment: "The Google C++ Testing Framework provides functions for comparing two floating-point quantities up to a given precision". Is there any doc for the precision?

Comment: @voxoid You can use [EXPECT_NEAR](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_NEAR) if that is your use case

Comment: @ZiqiFan The [documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ) says "to within 4 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)s". So in C++ terms I would guess `4 * std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`

Answer (score -6):

This is just a bug in Googletest. Text output should prove the failure, but format of it is not specified precisely.

Comment: This is not a bug in gtest, but a property of numbers in floating point representation. Here's a reference https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I believe the poster is saying that it's a bug that the text output doesn't have enough decimal places to show that the two do not match. Not that the numbers should match.