# Inaccuracy when using modulo in Lua

Tags: floating-point, lua, floating-accuracy, modulo

I used modulo (%) in Lua just a moment ago and I noticed that it was for some reason very inaccurate. I used it in World of Warcraft, but I would assume that it's at least somewhat up to date.

Anyhow, using the following example, the output would be 1;

```
print((0.6/(0.1^(2-1)))%1)
```

But when I use the following, it would return 0;

```
print((0.6*(10^(2-1)))%1)
```

And as far as I have been educated, 0.6/0.1 should be equivalent to 0.6*10.

It's not really a question or a problem, but I am merely curious about the cause. Inaccuracies in maths would be quite devastating in my opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a simple example of floating point/rounding error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look in the Lua manual, the `%` operation is defined as

```
 a % b == a - math.floor(a/b)*b
```

And so the expression

```
 6 - math.floor(6/1) * 1
```

will equal zero.

However, due to floating point inaccuracies (`0.1` does not exist as a floating point number, the closest should be `0.1000000014...`), these should be your intermediate results:

```
> print(math.floor(0.6*10))
6
> print(math.floor(0.6/.1))
5
```

So you get

```
6 - 6 * 1 = 0
6 - 5 * 1 = 1
```

### Further Reading

- [Lua Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.1)
- [Wikipedia: Floating-Point accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Comment: Ah, that makes everything a lot clearer. Thank you for your explanation, the fact that it wouldn't work as I had intended while being seemingly so logical bothered me a lot for no apparent reason. Cheers!

Comment: Another good reference is "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/800-7895/800-7895.pdf)."

Comment: @DiederikHu It is always a good thing to know about the problems of floating point numbers. As Tom Blodget hinted, this is a universal issue with floating point numbers in practically *any* language