# I got different results with pow(10,2) and pow(10,j), j=2;

Tags: c, floating-point, pow

This one prints 100:

```
int j=2;
int i= pow(10,2);  
printf("%d\n", i);
```

and this one prints 99:

```
int j=2;
int i= pow(10,j);  
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Why?

Comment: What compiler are you using and on what system?

Comment: My guess is this is integer truncation of the double result, it would be interesting to see what the `"%f"` output looks like.

Comment: One has a literal argument and the other an non-literal argument. So different code is called with different precisions. For example `gcc` has a `pow` builtin called when the arguments are both literals. In this case it would use the builtin for the first program and call the library function for the second program.

Comment: mingw (devc++) on windows 7 ultimate 64bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [pow() cast to integer, unexpected result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417788/pow-cast-to-integer-unexpected-result)

Comment: Nice try to blame Microsoft, but this is GCC compiling for x86-64. Up to the actual call of `pow`, there is not a single bit (literally) for which Microsoft is responsible. Fully a GCC deficiency, then.

Comment: @MSalters: No, it's definitely MS's fault, or rather mingw's fault for using buggy MS code. Mingw is a C implementation using GCC as the compiler and MSVCRT.DLL (Microsoft's libc) as the standard library. The buggy `pow` is part of the latter.

Comment: @R.. : Reread the question. The difference is not the `pow` call, but the initialization of its arguments (via literal versus variable). IEEE 754 does not require `pow` to be bit-perfect (only `+-/* sqrt`) so the Microsoft implementation is standards compliant.

Comment: @MSalters: As stated, it maybe conforming, but even if so, it's an extremely low quality of implementation. There's no justification for making a function return wrong results for arguments where the correct result is exactly representable and trivial to compute correctly. The compiler's choice of optimizations explains the discrepency, but there would not have been any discrepency had the library version returned the correct result.

Comment: @R..: Different implementations have different tradeoffs. Another important property of `pow(x,y)` is that `pow(x1,y) > pow(x2,y)` if `x1>x2 && y2>1`. Special-casing some values may break this.

Comment: @MSalters: That property, as stated with strict inequality, is impossible to satisfy by a simple counting argument; the only way it could be true is if `pow(x,y)==x` for all x,y. If you fix it to use `<=` instead of `<`, then any sane implementation handling exact results correctly would satisfy your (modified) condition.

Comment: You Can Refer To This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164550/what-is-happening-here-in-pow-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does gcc compiler output pow(10,2) as 99 not 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474351/why-does-gcc-compiler-output-pow10-2-as-99-not-100)

Comment: duplicates: [Why does pow(5,2) become 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264236/995714), [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What's going on is that you have a C implementation whose standard library has a very low quality implementation of `pow` which is returning inexact results even when the exact result is representable in the type (`double`). The call to `pow(10,2)` seems to producing the value just below `100.0`, which, when rounded to an integer, yields 99. The reason you don't see this when the arguments are constant is that the compiler took the liberty to optimize out the call alltogether and replace it with a constant 100 at compiletime.

If your intent is to do integer powers, don't use the `pow` function. Write a proper integer power function, or when the exponent is known, just write out the multiplication directly.

Comment: Yes, even if pow library does compute exact result properly rounded, relying on every integer to be represented exactly in double is fragile. I'm waiting the avent of 64 bits int to ask why pow(11,18) is not properly computed.

Comment: In practice it's safe from that standpoint. `int` will never change in practical (non-DSP) implementations due to many issues related to unexpected effects of integer promotion, the problems of omitting one size step from the standard types, and simply plain legacy compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, I suspect the compiler has optimized the value to `10*10` without actually calling `pow` (compilers do actually do this).  In the second case, it looks like you have a floating-point rounding error.  The result is *almost* 100 but not quite, and the implicit cast to `int` truncates it.

The `pow` function operates on `double`, not `int`.

In general (but not always), when you convert doubles to integers, you call `round()`.  Eg:

```
int i = (int) round(pow(10,j));
```

If your C library doesn't have this, you can emulate:

```
#define round(x) floor((x)+0.5)
```

Comment: small typo: `pow(10, 2) == 10*10` not `10 << 1`

Answer (score 0):

`pow` returns `double` and so if the result is not exactly `100` but slightly less than it will truncate when converting to an `int` and you will receive the `99` result you are seeing. It would be interesting to see what the results look like for a `double` variable and `%f` format.

The reason you won't see it when you use literals is because of [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) which will cause the call to `pow` to be optimized out and replaced with a constant. We can see the version that uses constants when we generate the assembly no call to `pow` is made it just moves the end result `100`(*see it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9acebb16d59ac3f7)*):

```
movl    $100, -4(%rbp)
```

while the version the second version actually calls `pow`(*see it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebd0be41358f95cf)*):

```
call    pow
```

Comment: i got 100 both times with double.