# Why does gcc compiler output pow(10,2) as 99 not 100?

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int j=2;
    int output;
    output=pow(10,j);
    cout<<output;
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote above code to gcc 12 compiler and got the output 99 instead 100. I don't get the valid reason while searching on various sites. Is there any compiler problem?

Comment: `<iostream.h>` is non standard

Comment: Switch on your compiler warnings. And get a standards compliant compiler.

Comment: I get 100 for `int(pow(10, 2))` w/ GCC on Linux/x86-64.

Comment: it all depends how pow is implemented

Comment: Perhaps [**this may help**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704195/why-pow10-5-9-999-in-c)

Comment: Why oh why do people use `pow()` to square an int ?

Comment: @PaulR - probably(hopefully!) for the same reason we see this question - inexperience. :shrug:

Comment: @enhzflep: you're probably right - I just keep seeing this kind of sloppy usage and it drives me nuts - why would you want to convert an int to a double, call an expensive library function to square that double, then convert the double result back to an int (with truncation and possible loss of accuracy, etc), when all you needed was a simple integer multiply?

Comment: I got pow(10,2)=100 but in case i declare j=2 and then upon evaluating  pow(10,j) i got 99.Why??

Comment: These were just bugs in gcc native libm, not evwn glibc's libm, all fixed now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of integer truncation. `pow()` returns a floating point value, and due to floating point arithmetic, it is probably ~ `99.999...`; however, due to integer truncation, even `99.999...` gets truncated down to 99.

Comment: This is most likely the case, and so in this situation to get the more 'correct' integer you could round the result from pow(). `int result = pow(10^2) + 0.5;` would do it.

Comment: @rsethc, That method of rounding has problems. Just use `std::round`.

Comment: Eh, care to give an example? Has always worked for me.

Comment: I got pow(10,2)=100 but in case i declare j=2 and then upon evaluating  pow(10,j) i got 99. Why is it so then if it returns only floating point value, it must stick to same answer in both case?

Comment: That was just a bug in pow() implementation in gcc, not even in libm of glibc.