# Why doesn't pow() function gives correct result to print armstrong number between two intervals but num*num*num gives in C++?

Tags: c++

I have tried to print Armstrong number between 100 and 1000; my code with pow() function print all numbers except 153. But when I tried to run the code `temp*temp*temp` it gives all numbers including 153. How?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int lower, upper;
    cout << "enter the lower and upper bound number";
    cin >> lower >> upper;
    cout<< "armstrong number are " << endl;
    for(int num = lower; num <= upper; num++) {
       int sum = 0, num1 =num,temp;
        while(num1 != 0) {
            temp = num1 % 10;
            // sum = sum + temp * temp * temp; [this gives a correct result]
            sum = sum + pow(temp,3);
            num1 = num1 / 10;
        }
        if(num == sum) 
            cout << num << endl;1
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't put floating-point math like `pow` in the middle of integer calculations unless you like *weird* things happening.

Comment: Because [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) operates on floating point numbers and [floating point math is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You don't even need a power of 3 to see possible issues using `pow`.  A [power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os) can give issues.

Comment: [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714), [Why does pow(5,2) become 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264236/995714), [Why does gcc compiler output pow(10,2) as 99 not 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25474351/995714)

Comment: Floating point maths is _not_ broken. Just many people's expectations of it are.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's fashionable to expect `pow` to return the best possible result, particularly with integral arguments<sup>1</sup>, neither the C++ standard nor the IEEE754 floating point standard insist on that.

And with a truncation of the `double` result to an `int`, your result *could* be 1 less than expected.

The solution is to write out small powers longhand: `temp * temp * temp` in your case.

You *might* get a better result with `std::pow` from `<cmath>` as then your compiler will pick an overload more suitable for your calculation.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact I'd consider an implementation of `pow` that gave an incorrect result for a third power of an integral argument defective.

Comment: I don't think pow() is working unexpectedly as if you put a `cout << pow(temp,3)` just after `sum = sum + pow(temp,3)` you will see expected result i.e 27, 125 and 1 on passing 153 and 153 as argument. But if you put `cout << sum` just after `sum = sum + pow(temp,3)` then unexpected result are shown i.e. 27, 151 and 152 . Instead of 151 there must be 152.... I hope you got my point.