# We are missing some condition for n>2, can someone help to find special cases which our code is missing?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, xor, lexicographic, bitwise-xor

Problem Statement:

You are given a sequence A1, A2,…, AN and you have to perform the following operation exactly X times:

- Choose two integers i and j such that 1≤i<j≤N.
- Choose a non-negative integer p.
- Change Ai to Ai⊕2p, and change Aj to Aj⊕2p, where ⊕ denotes bitwise XOR.

Find the lexicographically smallest sequence which can be obtained by performing this operation exactly X times.

A copy of the question can be https://www.codechef.com/DEC20B/problems/HXOR

Approach:

Here, we are dealing with N integers for X times operations, we are performing the xor function for all integers in an array with the power of 2 elements (2^p), p represents the non -ve integer.

For finding lexicographically smallest sequence, we are doing xor of each element until it becomes smallest and then we shift to the next element. Meanwhile, we also store the elements used in the previous steps to make pairs.

Test Case:

Input:

4 3

2 2 3 3

Output:

0 0 0 0

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define fast ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);

#define ll long long

#define pb push_back


ll bs(vector<ll> check, ll key){
    ll n = check.size();
    for(ll i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(check[i]==key)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

ll highestPowerof2(ll n)
{
   ll p = (ll)log2(n);
   return (ll)pow(2, p);
}

void smallestSequence()
{
    ll t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        ll n,x;
        cin >> n >> x;
        ll a[n];
        for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin >> a[i];
        }

        if(n==2)
        {
            for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
            {
                a[i]^=a[0];
            }
            a[0]=0;

            if(x%2==0)
            {
                a[0]^=1;
                for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
                {
                    a[i]^=1;
                }   
            }
            
            for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                cout << a[i] <<" ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            continue;
        }
        ll temp = x;
        x = 2*x;

        vector <ll> check;
        ll i;
        ll flag=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            ll p=1;
            while(a[i]!=0 && x>0)
            {
                if(bs(check, highestPowerof2(a[i]))>=0)
                {
                    check.erase(check.begin()+ bs(check, highestPowerof2(a[i])));
                }
                else{
                    if(temp>0)
                    {
                        check.pb(highestPowerof2(a[i]));
                        temp--;
                    }else {
                        ll j = 0;
                        ll si = check.size();
                        for(j=0; j<si; j++)
                        {
                            ll res = check[j]^a[i];
                            if(res<=a[i])
                            {
                                a[i]^=check[j];
                                x--;
                                check.erase(check.begin()+j);
                                j--;
                                si--;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                a[i]^=highestPowerof2(a[i]);
                x--;
            }

            if(a[i]!=0)
            {
                flag=1;
            }
        }
        
        // if(flag==0 && temp>0 && (temp*2)==x)
        // {
        //  if(temp%2==1)
        //  {
        //      a[n-1]=a[n-2]=1;
        //  }
        // }

        while(x>=0 && !check.empty())
        {
            a[i-1]^=check[0];
            check.erase(check.begin());
        }

        for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout << a[i] <<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    fast;

    smallestSequence();

    return 0;
}
```

Suggestions will be appreciated! I had been trying for this problem for almost 5 days now, I don't want a solution, I just want to know some special TCs where my code is giving WAs.

Comment: Is is `2p` or `2^p` ?

Comment: I recommend decrypting your code. Don't use `pow` to get integer exponents. You will get errors because of [floating point imprecision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Use bitshifting `1<< p` instead. For the same reason, `log2` may have strange results.

Comment: TCs that give WAs? Don't assume such abrreviations are common knowledge outside of coding contests, they aren't. I usually have test cases and they either fail or pass.

Comment: 2^p is the power of 2 integers, where p is a non-negative integer. @Damien

Comment: @i know. But you mention `2p` at the beginning of the post

Comment: This is a question in a still running contest. Not Cool.
https://www.codechef.com/DEC20B/problems/HXOR

Comment: as said, don't use pow for integer powers. See [Why does gcc compiler output pow(10,2) as 99 not 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25474351/995714), [Why does pow(n,2) return 24 when n=5, with my compiler and OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25678481/995714). But especially for powers of 2 you should never use `pow` which is not only imprecise sometimes but also hundreds or thousands of time slower. Use `1 << p` to get 2^p

Answer (score 0):

This is a on going contest.
So this is the best i could help you.

**Input:**

```
1
4 4
1 2 3 4
```

**Your output:**

```
0 0 0 4
```

**Right output:**

```
0 0 1 5
```