# Why is pow() function in C giving wrong answer when it is odd exponential of 10 in a loop?

Tags: c, loops, math, pow

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int loop, place_value=0, c = 5;
    for(loop = 0; loop < c; loop++)
    {
        place_value = 0;
        place_value = pow(10, loop);
        printf("%d \n", place_value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives

```
10 
99 
1000 
9999
```

Why is 99 and 9999  there in 3rd and 5th line instead of 100 and 10000 respectively?

When asking for power normally, it gives right answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  printf ("%d", (int) pow (10,3 ));
  return 0;
}
```

```
1000
```

Comment: Looks like a rounding problem

Comment: `pow` works with floating-point number, it's generally not guaranteed to return an exact answer. Here, you round its return value (probably something like `99.9999999999`) down and get `99` instead of `100`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/

Comment: @Jabberwocky if its a rounding problem, why only in odd exponentials and  when function is outside of a loop, why is it working as it should.

Comment: `pow` is meant for use on floating point, don't use it for integers.

Comment: What is you output if you replace `int place_value` with `double place_value` and `printf("%d \n", place_value)` with `printf("%lf \n", place_value)`?

Comment: In your second example the compiler might decide to optimize the code by completely removing the call to `pow` and using `1000` instead. That is not possible in a loop

Comment: @Jabberwocky 1.000000 
10.000000 
100.000000 
1000.000000 
10000.000000

Comment: Still, given that the result of `pow(10, 2)` can be represented exactly as `double` (unless your machine is very weird), you would hope that `pow` would be implemented well enough to give that result.  What compiler and system is this?

Comment: @Gerhardh It might not be allowed to do that for numerical reasons unless you disable the strict floating point mode.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am using Win10 64 bit i5,  on VScode text editor. I don't know how to check  compiler.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I get the correctly-rounded results with gcc and clang.

Comment: Try `round(pow(10, loop))`

Comment: @IanAbbott: Strict floating-point does not preclude optimizing `pow(10, 3)` to `1000`: The result is exact, not dependent on rounding mode, not affected by rules about infinities or NaNs, and does not raise any exception flags. So replacing it by `1000` does not violate any strictness requirements.

Comment: @PaulHankin How to check compiler ?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Though it would be confusing if it returns different results depending on whether `pow` gets optimized out or not. Maybe a quality of implementation issue?

Comment: @IanAbbott: Yes, it is a quality of implementation issue. `pow` can reasonably be implemented with error less than 1 ULP. (The ideal is correct rounding, which has error at most ½ ULP, but that is hard.) Apple’s `pow` has sub-ULP accuracy, and a consequence of that is that whenever the mathematical result is exactly representable, it is returned. So Apple’s `pow(10, loop)` returns exact answers for `loop` in [0, 27], after which the exact answers are not representable (if I got that upper bound right).

Comment: [Why does pow(5,2) become 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264236/995714), [Why does pow(n,2) return 24 when n=5, with my compiler and OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25678481/995714)

Answer (score 5):

`pow` is a difficult routine to implement, and not all implementations give good results. Roughly speaking, the core algorithm for `pow(x, y)` computes a logarithm from (a part of) `x`, multiplies it by `y`, and computes an exponential function on the product. Doing this in floating-point introduces rounding errors that are hard to control.

The result is that the computed result for `pow(10, 4)` may be something near 10,000 but slightly less or greater. If it is less, than converting it to an integer yields 9999.

When you use arguments hard-coded in source code, the compiler may compute the answer during compilation, possibly using a different algorithm. For example, when `y` is three, it may simply multiply the first argument by itself, as in `x*x*x`, rather than using the logarithm-exponent algorithm.

As for why the low result happens with the odd numbers you have tested, consider what happens when we multiply 5.45454545 by various powers of 10 and round to an integer. 5.45454545 rounds down to 5. 54.5454545 rounds up to 55. 545.454545 rounds down to 545. The rounding up or down is a consequence of what fraction happens to land beyond the decimal point. For your cases with `pow(10, loop)`, the bits of the logarithm of 10 may just happen to give this pattern with the few odd numbers you tried.

Comment: Is there a better alternative than pow? It is the only result i got searching for exponential function.

Comment: @user541396: Since you are just using powers incrementally, start with `int p = 1;` and multiply `p` by ten in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @user541396: Perhaps surprisingly, there is no standard function for this, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int describes a lot of possible options.  A reasonable first approach would be a simple multiplication loop with special handling for the bases `0, 1, -1`.

Comment: @user541396 or simply use `round` like this: `round(pow(10, loop))`

Comment: I was just about to vote to close the question as still another duplicate of "Is floating point math broken?" (since in many ways, it is) but then I read this answer. It seems sufficiently informative that the question is best left open.

Comment: @JohnColeman A [merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question) would be better.

Comment: @EricPostpischil smart implementations check for those most popular bases or exponents and not always choose this longest path :).

Answer (score 1):

`pow(x, y)` function translate more or less to `exp(log(x) * y)`, which will give a result that is not quite the same as x ^ y.

In order to solve this issue you can round this:

```
round(pow(x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb: never use floating point functions (especially such a complicated ones like pow or log) with integer numbers.

Simply implement integer pow

```
unsigned intpow(unsigned x)
{
    unsigned result = 1;
    while(x --) result *= 10;
    return result;
}
```

it will be much faster or even (the fastest one)

```
int intpow1(unsigned x)
{
    const static unsigned vals[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, /* ... */};

    #if defined(CHECK_OVERFLOW)
    if(x >= sizeof(vals)/ sizeof(vals[0])) return -1;
    #endif

    return vals[x];
}
```