# Conversion of Binary to Decimals

Tags: c++

I am writing a c++ program where the program takes the t test cases as input and asks the binary input t times, and after that displays the output.
I tried to code but for 1st test case it displays right output in decimal format but for further test cases its not displaying correct output result.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {   
    long int num;
    int  r=0,i=0,t,dec=0;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        cin>>num;

        while (num!=0) {
            r = num% 10;
            num /= 10;
            dec += r * pow(2, i);
            ++i;
        }
        cout<<dec<<"\n"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code if run for lets say 2 test cases , lets say first one is 101 , it displays 5 which is fine but on the second input , lets say 111 , it displays output 61.
I am not sure where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: Have you tried single stepping through your code with a debugger yet? If not try that first and check where a value starts to differ from what you expect. Debugging is a skill that you will need a lot so best start learning about it today :)

Comment: I think the issue might be with the `dec` variable not getting reset back to zero in the `while(t--)` loop.

Comment: never use `r * pow(2, i)`. Use `r << i` instead

Comment: @phuclv r * pow(2, i) is being used for mathematical calculation. What it has to do with r<<i

Comment: @AviralMishra it's the shift operator and is one of the most basic things that you need to learn first when learning a programming language. Read a book first [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714). Using `pow` for integer power is not only hundreds of times slower but may also produce incorrect results: [Why does pow(5,2) become 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264236/995714), [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `i`, `dec` outside the outer while loop. Initialize them to 0 inside the outer while loop and it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    
    while(t--)
    {
        int num, r, dec = 0, i = 0;
        cin >> num;

        while (num != 0) {
            r = num % 10;
            num /= 10;
            dec += r * pow(2, i);
            //cout << r << " " << num << " " << i << " " << dec << endl;
            ++i;
        }
        cout << dec << "\n"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is C function `strtoull`, which is doing the job

*Example:*

```
cat bin2dec.cpp 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {   
    string num;
    int  t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        cin>>num;
        auto dec = strtoull(num.c_str(), NULL, 2);
        cout << dec << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
g++ -O2 -o bin2dec bin2dec.cpp
```

```
2
111
7
100000000000
2048
```

```
g++ --version | head -1
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can use the division and remainder method, C++ provides [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and the string conversion [std::stoul, std::stoull](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) that can automate the conversion for you.

The following example loops prompting the user for input of a binary value and converts the value to `unsigned long` so long as the binary digits entered are 64 or less. Simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering a value to end the program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
  
  for (;;) {                    /* loop continually */
    std::string input{};        /* binary input from user */
    unsigned long value = 0;    /* value to hold conversion to ulong */
    
    /* prompt for input, read/validate input */
    std::cout << "\nenter a binary value: ";
    if (!getline(std::cin, input) || input.size() == 0) {
      break;
    }
    
    if (input.size() > 64) {  /* validate 64 binary digits or less */
      std::cerr << "error: input exceeds 64-bit conversion limit.\n";
      continue;
    }
    
    value = std::bitset<64>(input).to_ulong();    /* convert to ulong */
    std::cout << input << ": " << value << '\n';  /* output result */
  }
}
```

Note: you would also want to validate the user has entered only `'0'`s and `'1'`s which you can do simply with [std::basic_string::find_first_not_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of), e.g.

```cpp
    if (input.find_first_not_of("01") != std::string::npos) {
      std::cerr << "error: invalid input not '0' and '1'\n";
      continue;
    }
```

(simply add the `if` statement before the conversion and assignment to `value`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
./bin/bitset_to_ulong

enter a binary value: 1010
1010: 10

enter a binary value: 10000000
10000000: 128

enter a binary value: 1111
1111: 15

enter a binary value: 1234
error: invalid input not '0' and '1'

enter a binary value:
```

Just an alternative way of doing the same that C++ has provided a convenient way to do in C++11 and forward.