# Find digit in an integer at user requested position

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to take a user entered integer (positive or negative) and let them pick a digit position and output the digit at that position.

```
int findDigAtPos(int number)
{
    int position;
    int result;

    cout << "Enter digit position between 1 and " << std::to_string(number).length() << endl;
    cin >> position;

    while (position < 0 || position > std::to_string(number).length())
    {
         cout << "Enter digit position between 1 and "<< std::to_string(number).length()<<endl;
         cin >> position;
    }

    if (std::to_string(number).length() == 1)
        cout << "Only one digit" << endl;

    number = number / pow(10, (position - 1.0));
    result = number % 10;
    
    return result;
}
```

This is the code I currently have for the function. However, it outputs the number in reverse. How do I correct the digit position? I thought it didn't even function correctly until noticing it's in reverse order.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you shouldn't be using the `pow` function when working with integers, because it returns a `double` result, which can cause problems [due to unexpected truncation of the result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26941558/10871073).

But, if you *insist* on using it, then you need to remember that the power of 10 by which to divide will *decrease* as the digit position *increases*: i.e., the position is given with the **leftmost** (most significant) digit in position 1. Thus, that power of 10 will be total number of digits *minus* the position:

```cpp
number = number / pow(10, (std::to_string(number).length() - position));
result = number % 10;
```

The safer method (not using `pow`) would be a small loop, like this:

```cpp
for (int d = std::to_string(number).length() - position; d > 0; --d) number /= 10;
result = number % 10;
```

However, as you're already converting the passed number to a string, then why not just save that string and extract the digit from it – at `position-1`, because array (and string) indexes in C++ are zero-based:

```cpp
int findDigAtPos(int number)
{
    int position;
    std::string str = std::to_string(std::abs(number)); // If -ve, remove sign!
    int ndig = str.length();
    std::cout << "Enter digit position between 1 and " << ndig << "\n";
    std::cin >> position;
    while (position < 0 || position > ndig) {
        std::cout << "Enter digit position between 1 and " << ndig << "\n";
        std::cin >> position;
    }
    return str.at(position-1) - '0';
}
```

Note that the codes (ASCII or otherwise) for the numeric digits, `0` thru `9` are **guaranteed** by the C++ standard to be contiguous and in order, so subtracting the value of the digit `0` will 'convert' any digit to its actual, numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
number = number / pow(10, (position - 1.0));
result = number % 10;
```

This:

```
int length = (int)(std::to_string(number).length());
while (position < length)
{
    number = number / 10;
    length--;
}

result = number % 10;
```

The above should work fine for positive numbers. For negative numbers, you might need to a fixup. I'll leave that as an exercise for you to manage.