# Power of integers in C returns peculiar result

Tags: c, gcc

The following code is simple. As expected, it should print `100, 100`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a = 10, b, c;
    b = pow(10, 2);
    c = pow(a, 2);
    printf("%d, %d\n", b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

On **OS X 10.10, clang**, the result is as expected. On **Windows 10, gcc**, the result is however `100, 99`.

[image: screenshot]

What is the cause of it?

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19126809/1009479

Comment: At least OP tried with 2 different compilers, so it's noteworthy one of them *happened* to give the right answer and the other one did not. (For these two numbers *only*. It's not as if clang will *always* get it right. Even when it does, it's only their implementation, rather than some fault in gcc.)

Comment: In codeblocks version 10 on Ubuntu, your code giving me correct result.