# Why doesn't this code remove the middle digits?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,l=0,a,s,d,w;
    cin>>n;
    a=n;
    while(a!=0){
        l++;
        a=a/10;
    }
    if(l%2==0){
        s=n/pow(10,(l/2)+1);
        w=pow(10,(l/2)-1);
        d=n%w;
        } else{
        s=n/pow(10,l/2+1);
        w=pow(10,l/2);
        d=n%w;
    }
    cout<<s*(pow(10,(l/2)-1));
}
```

When I input "12345" it should show "1245", but instead it shows "120". Why does it?
The code should eliminate the middle digit for uneven numbers, or two middle digits for even numbers, but the right side of the number (variable d) doesn't show the right thing.

Comment: Did you try stepping through it line by line?

Comment: @alexb Then why didn't you mention the specific line that doesn't do what you expect it to do, what you expect it to do, and what it did?

Comment: This would be much easier to do by manipulating the text directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,l=0,a,s,d,w, result;
    cin>>n;
    a=n;
    while(a!=0)
    {
        l++;
        a=a/10;
    }
    if(l%2==0)
    {
        s=n/ceil(pow(10,(l/2)+1));
        w=ceil(pow(10,(l/2)-1));
        d=n%w;
        result = s*(ceil(pow(10,(l/2-1))))+d;
    }
    else
    {
        s=n/ceil(pow(10,l/2+1));
        w=ceil(pow(10,l/2));
        d=n%w;
        result = s*(ceil(pow(10,(l/2))))+d;
    }
    cout<<result<<endl;
}
```

[ceil](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/) used to handle [double precision problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126809/c-i-got-different-results-with-pow10-2-and-pow10-j-j-2) with `pow`.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is not part of the output.  so it's calculation will not be shown.

```
if(l%2==0){
    s=n/pow(10,(l/2)+1);
    w=pow(10,(l/2)-1);
    d=n%w;
    } else{
    s=n/pow(10,l/2+1);
    w=pow(10,l/2);
    d=n%w;
    // if n == 12345, I get
    // s = 12
    // w = 100
    // d = 45
    // l = 5
}
cout<<s*(pow(10,(l/2)-1));
// outputs 120 (s * 10^ 1) == s * 10
```

I can see `d` not used, but what further is unexpected

Comment: But if I `cout<<s<<";"<<d;` it shows _12;69_ for 12345, where it should show _12;45_

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `d` part to your last calculation:
`l` should be modified for even and odd differently.

Try:

```
if(l%2==0){
    s=n/pow(10,(l/2)+1);
    w=pow(10,(l/2)-1);
    d=n%w;
    l = l/2 - 1;
} else{
    s=n/pow(10,(l/2) + 1); 
    w=pow(10,l/2); 
    d=n%w; 
    l = l/2;
}
cout<<s * pow(10, l) + d<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Did you try with the given code (`from if to last`) ??  I am getting 1245 for 12345.

Comment: I did try with this:
`#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,l=0,a,s,d,w;
    cin>>n;
    a=n;
    while(a!=0){
        l++;
        a=a/10;
    }
if(l%2==0){
    s=n/pow(10,(l/2)+1);
    w=pow(10,(l/2)-1);
    d=n%w;
    l = l/2 - 1;
} else{
    s=n/pow(10,(l/2) + 1);
    w=pow(10,l/2);
    d=n%w;
    l = l/2;
}
cout<<s * pow(10, l) + d<<endl;
}
`

Comment: The code did work for me. May be you need to compile it before test!!