# does printf dont take integer constant as arguement?

Tags: c, printf

What's the problem with this code ?

```
   printf("%d", pow(2, 10));
```

as format specifier used is integral , it should give an integer value . But it don't . Why so ?

output -
0

Expected output -
1024

Comment: I believe the return value is floating point.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417788/pow-cast-to-integer-unexpected-result) for a good explanation (casting also wont work on tcc... from what i read)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pow` return `double`. You are using wrong specifier to print a `double` value. This will invoke undefined behavior and you may get either expected or unexpected result.  Use `%f` instead.

```
 printf("%f", pow(2, 10));
```

Answer (score 4):

The `pow` function from `<math.h>` returns type `double`.

The format specifier for `double` is `%f`. You used the wrong specifier, so your program causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939). Literally anything could happen.

To fix this, use `%f` instead.

BTW if you want to compute `2` to the power `10` in integers you can write `1 << 10`.

Answer (score 1):

cast to int

```
printf("%d", (int)pow(2, 10));
```