# How does computer convert floating point numbers to decimal string?

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, precision

When I run the following code, the output is accurately the number 2<sup>500</sup> in decimal.

(g++ 5.3.1 on ubuntu)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout.precision(0);
    cout << fixed << pow(2.0,500.0);
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder how C++ converted this floating point number to its decimal string at such a high precision.

I know that 2<sup>500</sup> can be accurately presented in IEEE 754 format. But I think `mod 10` and `divided by 10` can cause precision loss on floating point numbers. What algorithm is used when the conversion proceed?

Comment: Carefully, I suggest you look at the open source implementations.  This blog may also give you some idea of the sort of problems: http://www.exploringbinary.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to convert an IEEE 754 double to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153979/algorithm-to-convert-an-ieee-754-double-to-a-string)

Comment: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/printf_fp.c.html#418

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there exists an exact double-precision floating-point representation for 2<sup>500</sup>. You should not assume that `pow(2.0,500.0)` produces this value, though. There is no guarantee of accuracy for the function `pow`, and you may find [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417788/pow-cast-to-integer-unexpected-result) that arose from `pow(10.0, 2.0)` not producing `100.0`, although the mathematical result was perfectly representable too.

But anyway, to answer your question, the conversion from the floating-point binary representation to decimal does not in general rely on floating-point operations, which indeed would be too inaccurate for the intended accuracy of the end result. In general, accurate conversion requires [reliance on big integer arithmetics](http://www.exploringbinary.com/correct-decimal-to-floating-point-using-big-integers/). In the case of 2<sup>500</sup>, for instance, the naïve algorithm would be to repeatedly divide the big integer written in binary `1000…<500 zeroes in total>…` by ten.

There are some cases where floating-point arithmetic can be used, for instance taking advantage of the fact that powers of 10 up to 10<sup>23</sup> are represented exactly in IEEE 754 double-precision. But correctly rounded conversion between binary floating-point and decimal floating-point always require big integer arithmetics in general, and this is particularly visible far away from 1.0.

Comment: Or BigDecimal (which often use BigInteger internally).

Comment: I assume that pow() internally use exponentiation based on `e` and natural logarithms, so that this is accurate could well be pure coincidence, indeed. Or perhaps some pow() implementations are different for integer arguments?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Regardless of how it is implemented, it only needs to be designed to be “faithful” (error < 1ULP) to guarantee that `pow(2.0,500.0)` will come out as 0x1.0p500, since this is the only double-precision number at a distance of 1 ULP of 2^500.

Comment: I'd guess that there are quite a few compiler runtimes where this doesn't apply, i.e. where you'll see differences of more than 1 ulp.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yes that was the painful lesson of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417788/pow-cast-to-integer-unexpected-result

Comment: Ok, that was a very extreme example. <g>