# C++ I've just read that floats are inexact and do not store exact integer values. What does this mean?

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

I am thinking of this at a binary level.

would a float of value 1 and an integer of value 1 not compile down to (omitting lots of zeros here)

0001

If they do both compile down to this then where does this inexactness come in.

Resource I'm using is http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson1.html

Thanks.

Comment: See e.g. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format for how floats are usually stored. This should answer your question.

Comment: Whole numbers can be represented exactly with floats.

Comment: A float can store 7 significant digits.  So of course an integer value that has more than 7 digits cannot be stored precisely.  Not a problem with 1, the first integer value is 16777217.  Try it.

Comment: After reading Wikipedia, you can mess around with IEEE754 floating point at http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_float.html . Example values that can be stored exactly (32-bit float): [1](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049), [42](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=052050), [0.25](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=048046050053). Examples that can't: [0.4](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=048046052), [123456789](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049050051052053054055056057). Have fun =)

Comment: See: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible. Floating point numbers are represented in an exponential notation (a*2^n), where  some bits represent a (the *significand*), and some bits represent n (the *exponent*).

You can't uniquely represent all the integers in the range of a floating point value, due to the so-called *pigeonhole principle*. For example, 32-bit floats go up to over 10^38, but on 32 bits you can only represent 2^32 values - that means some integers will have the same representation.

Now, what happens when you try to, for example, do the following:

```
x = 10^38 - (10^38 - 1)
```

You should get 1, but you probably won't, because 10^38 and 10^38-1 are so close to each other that the computer has to represent them the same way. So, your 1.0f will usually be 1, but if this 1 is a result of calculation, it might not be.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error) are some examples.

Answer (score 6):

To be precise: Integers can be exactly represented as floats if their binary representation does not use more bits than the float format supplies for the mantissa plus an implicit one bit.

IEEE floats have a mantissa of 23 bits, add one implicit bit, and you can store any integer representable with 24 bits in a `float` (that's integers up to 16777216). Likewise, a double has 52 mantissa bits, so it can store integers up to 9007199254740992.

Beyond that point, the IEEE format omits first the odd numbers, then all numbers not divisible by 4, and so on. So, even `0xffffff00ul` is exactly representable as a float, but `0xffffff01ul` is not.

So, yes, you can represent integers as floats, and as long as they don't become larger than the 16e6 or 9e15 limits, you can even expect additions between integers in float format to be exact.

Answer (score 4):

A `float` will store an `int` exactly if the `int` is less than a certain number, but if you have a large enough `int`, there won't be enough bits in the mantissa to store all the bits of the integer.  The missing bits are then assumed to be zero.  If the missing bits aren't zero, then your `int` won't be equal to your `float`.

Comment: **Some** integers above a threshold cannot be stored in a `float`. These are the odd numbers between 8*1024*1024 and 16*1024*1024, the numbers that are not multiples of 4 between 16*1024*1024 and 32*1024*1024, and so on. Some very large numbers, like 3*2^100, are stored exactly in a `float`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: good point.  I've updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** no, the floating point representation of integers is not that simple.

---

The representation adopted for the `float` type by the C language standard is called [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) single-precision and is probably more complicated than most people would like to delve into, but the link describes it thoroughly in case you're interested.

As for the representation of the integer 1: we can see how it's encoded in the 32-bit base-2 single-precision format defined by IEEE 754 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Single-precision_examples) - `3f80 0000`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose letters stand for a bit, 0/1. Then a floating point number looks (schematically) like:

```
smmmmee
```

where s is the sign +/- and the number is `.mmmm x 10 ^ ee`

Now if you have two immediately following numbers:

```
.mmm0 x 10 ^ ee
.mmm1 x 10 ^ ee
```

Then for large exponent ee the difference might be more then 1.

And of course in base 2 a number like 1/5, 0.2, cannot represented exact. Summing fractions wil increase the error.

*(Note this is not the exact representation.)*

Comment: I think you have the mantissa and the exponent flipped, it should be SEEMMMM

Comment: @GeorgeMitchell yes; I almost used the real order. I kept it in the human readable order. If one would be interested in the bit representation, more is needed (number of bits, NaN, numeric boundaries); the reference is readable enough.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to some modern dynamically typed programming languages such as JavaScript or Ruby that have a single basic numeric type, the C programming language has many. That is because C reflects the different way to represent different kinds of numbers within a processor register.

To investigate different representations you can use the `union` construct where the same data can be viewed as different types.

Define

```
union {
  float x;
  int v;
} u;
```

Assign `u.x = 1.0f` and `printf("0x%08x\n",u.v)` to get the 32-bit representation of `1.0f` as a floating point number. It should return `0x3f800000` and not `0x00000001` as one might expect.

As mentioned in earlier answers this reflects the representation of a floating number as a 32-bit value as `

```
    1.0f = 0x3F800000 = 0011.1111.1000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000 =
                 0 0111.1111 000.0000.0000.0000.0000.0000 = 0 0x7F 0
```

Here the three parts are *sign* s=0, *exponent* e=127, and *mantissa* m=0 and the floating point value is computed as

```
   value = s * (1 + m * 2^-23) * 2^(e-127)
```

With this representation any integer number from -16,777,215 to 16,777,215 can be represented exactly. This is the value of (2^24 - 1) since there are only 23 bits in the mantissa. This range is not sufficient for many applications, therefore the `float` type cannot replace the `int` type.

The range of exact representation of integers by the `double` type is wider since the value occupies 64 bits and there are 53 bits reserved for the mantissa. It is exactly from 
-9,007,199,254,740,991 to 9,007,199,254,740,991. Yet `double` requires twice as much memory.

Another source of difficulty is the way fractional numbers are represented. Since decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly (0.1f = 0x3dcccccd = 0.10000000149...) the use of floating point numbers breaks common algebraic identities.

```
0.1f * 10 != 1.0f
```

This can be confusing and lead to errors that are hard to detect. In general **strict equality should not be used with floating point numbers**.

Another example of floating point arithmetic depature from algebraic correctness:

```
float x = 16777217.0f;
float y = 16777215.0f;
x -= 1.0f;
y += 1.0f;
if (y > x) {printf("16777215.0 + 1.0 > 16777217.0 - 1.0\n");}
```

Yet another issue is the behaviour of the system when the limits of exact representation are broken. When in integer arithmetic the result of an arithmetic operation is greater than the range of the type, this can be detected in many ways: a special OVERFLOW bit in the processor flags register is flipped, and the result is significantly different from the expected.

In floating point arithmetic as the example above shows, the loss of precision occurs silently.

Hope this helps to understand why one needs many basic numeric types in C.

Answer (score 1):

> would a float of value 1 and an integer of value 1 not compile down to (omitting lots of zeros here) 0001

No, float will be stored like something similar to `0x00000803f`, depending on precision.

> What does this mean?

1. Some numbers cannot be precisely represented in binary form. `O.2` in binary form will look like `0.00110011001100110011...` which will keep going on(and repeating) forever. No matter how many bits you use to store it, it will be never enough. That's because 5 is not divisible by `2`. The only way to precisely represent it is to use ratios to store it.
2. floating points have limited precision. Roughly speaking, they only store certain amount of digits after first significant non-zero digit, and the rest will be lost. That'll result in errors, for example, with single precision floats `100000000000000001` and `100000000000000002` are most likely rounded off to the same number.

You might also want to read something like [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Conclusion:

If you're writing financial software, do not use floats. Use [Bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), using libraries like [gmp](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: `0x00000803f` - depending on precision and endianness.