# Calculating pow with doubles gives wrong results

Tags: c++, c, arduino, double, pow

I'm programming a calculator on an Arduino and I'm trying to calculate pow and writing it to a string (result). This is my code:

```
dtostrf(exp(n*log(x)), 0, 5, result); // x ^ n

2 ^ 2 = 4.00000 // works fine

10 ^ 5 = 99999.9770 // should be 100000
```

What's wrong with my code and how can I always get the right result?
I mean how can I round it but still be able to use doubles ( e.g. 5.2 ^ 3.123 )

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error).

Comment: Arduino Uno has a very simple processor without any floating point support.  A consequence is that *double* is not double precision at all, it takes 4 bytes and is emulated in software with single precision.  The loss of precision is of course inevitable, you can never count on more than 6 precise digits.  Finding solutions for problems like this is what keep Arduino enthusiasts busy.

Comment: Ok, so that means I could use floats instead of doubles?

Comment: No, a `float` is 4 bytes too. On a Due, a `double` will give more precision than a `float`; on an Uno, they'll be the same. A `float` will never have *more* precision than a `double`.

Comment: In embedded real-time systems, CPU:s without floating-point unit used to be quite common, at least in the early 90s. Luckily, nowadays most CPU:s have floating point and many have vector units as well. Since your CPU does not, you could revert to methods like Newton-Raphson, I have seen that used in real-time systems for computing e.g. square roots on CPUs that have only integer arithmetic. Maybe you could do something similar for pow().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just hitting rounding errors. There's nothing you can do about this, except revert to an integer-based approach whenever the inputs are integers.

You could condition on whether the inputs are integers, and if so then use integer arithmetic; if not, then use doubles. But using `exp` and `log` will always introduce rounding errors, so you can't expect exact answers with that approach.

More precisely, to use integer arithmetic, you need the base to be an integer and the exponent to be a non-negative integer.

Comment: Ok, but how can calculators get the right result while using doubles?

Comment: @AkimWright I suspect they also use integer arithmetic when the inputs are integers.

Comment: Ok my code now checks if floor(x) == x && floor(n) == n . It works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

Since you are programming a calculator, speed is not your concern but the number of reliable digits is. So, you could try to use a double precision library. It uses 64-Bit-doubles but has only about 200 FLOPS at 16MHz CPU clock and much less at higher-order calculations like exp(), log(), or sin(). Thus, it will take a second after having typed in the digits and pressed the enter button but this was also the case with the old 8-Bit-based pocket caluclators.

See this [Link (only in German)](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/85256)