# NumPy array_equal function not working as expected

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm observing very odd behavior of the function `array_equal` from `NumPy`. I'm sure I'm missing a very simple detail.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a unit test.

The facts is, I have array 1:

```
In[21]: bounds['lowerBound']

Out[21]: array([ 1. ,  1.2,  1.8])
```

And I have array 2:

```
In[22]: res['lowerBound']

Out[22]: array([ 1. ,  1.2,  1.8])
```

And just in case I did check their shapes:

```
In[26]: bounds['lowerBound'].shape
Out[26]: (3,)
In[28]: res['lowerBound'].shape
Out[28]: (3,)
```

Also the dtypes:

```
In[30]: res['lowerBound'].dtype
Out[30]: dtype('float64')
In[31]: bounds['lowerBound'].dtype
Out[31]: dtype('float64')
```

and still when I try to verify if they are the same:

```
In[29]:  np.array_equal(bounds['lowerBound'],res['lowerBound'])
Out[29]: False
```

How can that be ?

thanks in advance !

EDIT:
The code used to generate the data is:

```
bounds={'lowerBound':np.array([1.,1.2,1.8]), 'upperBound':np.array([10.,12.,18.])}
```

And the `res` dictionary is generated by the following function:

```
def generateAdjustedBounds(self,universeMktCap,lowerBound,upperBound):
    lb=np.zeros(len(universeMktCap))
    ub=np.zeros(len(universeMktCap))
    lb[0]=lowerBound
    ub[0]=upperBound

    for dat in range(1,len(lb)):
        lb[dat]=lb[dat-1]*universeMktCap[dat]/universeMktCap[dat-1]
        ub[dat]=ub[dat-1]*universeMktCap[dat]/universeMktCap[dat-1]

    Bounds={'lowerBound':np.array(lb),'upperBound':np.array(ub)}

    return Bounds
```

Comment: What are the dtypes here, can you post code to create your arrays

Comment: it is quite extensive. But I'll check for dtypes.  I'm quite new to python... give me a sec ! thanks !

Comment: Use `np.set_printoptions(precision=16)` to see the difference between the values.

Answer (score 8):

Because your elements are floats, you should probably use allclose() instead.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html

Comment: It works ! thanks ! when is it advisable to use array_equal though ?

Comment: Use array_equal when your array contains integers.

Comment: This occurs because any two floats that should represent the same number often don't, when small rounding errors are introduced in mathematically equivalent calculations. [Here are some examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error)