# How to round a large number in Shell command?

Tags: shell, terminal, rounding

In Mac terminal, I would like to round a large number.

For example,

At 10^13th place:
1234567812345678 --> 1230000000000000

Or at 10^12th place:
1234567812345678 --> 1235000000000000

So I would like to specify the place, and then get the rounded number.
How do I do this?

Comment: That looks more like truncation than rounding, and could be done with character substitutions using regexes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion):

```
$ val=1234567812345678
$ echo $(( ${val: -13:1} < 5 ? val - val % 10**13 : val - val % 10**13 + 10**13 ))
1230000000000000
$ echo $(( ${val: -12:1} < 5 ? val - val % 10**12 : val - val % 10**12 + 10**12 ))
1235000000000000
```

This checks if the most significant removed digit is 5 or greater, and if it is, the last significant unremoved digit is increased by one; then we subtract the division remainder from the (potentially modified) initial value.

If you don't want to have to write it this way, you can wrap it in a little function:

```
round () {
    echo $(( ${1: -$2:1} < 5 ? $1 - $1 % 10**$2 : $1 - $1 % 10**$2 + 10**$2 ))
}
```

which can then be used like this:

```
$ round "$val" 13
1230000000000000
$ round "$val" 12
1235000000000000
```

Notice that quoting `$val` isn't strictly necessary here, it's just a good habit.

If the one-liner is too cryptic, this is a more readable version of the same:

```
round () {
    local rounded=$(( $1 - $1 % 10**$2 ))   # Truncate

    # Check if most significant removed digit is >= 5
    if (( ${1: -$2:1} >= 5 )); then
        (( rounded += 10**$2 ))
    fi
    echo $rounded
}
```

Apart from arithmetic expansion, this also uses parameter expansion to get a substring: `${1: -$2:1}` stands for "take `$1`, count `$2` from the back, take one character". There has to be a space before `-$2` (or is has to be in parentheses) because otherwise it would be interpreted as a different expansion, checking if `$1` is unset or null, which we don't want.

Comment: Nicely done; much more elegant than what I came up with, so replaced my pure `bash` solution with a link to yours.

Comment: I got exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`awk`'s `[s]printf` function can do rounding for you, within the limits of double-precision floating-point arithmetic:

```
$ for p in 13 12; do 
  awk -v p="$p" '{ n = sprintf("%.0f", $0 / 10^p); print n * 10^p }' <<<1234567812345678
done
1230000000000000
1235000000000000
```

---

For a pure `bash` implementation, see [Benjamin W.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36682841/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to round to n significant digits you might be best served by mixing up traditional math and strings.

Serious debugging is left to the student, but this is what I quickly came up with for bash shell and hope MAC is close enough:

```
function rounder
{
    local value=$1;
    local digits=${2:-3};

    local zeros="$( eval "printf '0%.0s' {1..$digits}" )"; #proper zeros
        # a bit of shell magic that repats the '0' $digits times.

    if (( value > 1$zeros )); then
        # large enough to require rounding
        local length=${#value};
        local digits_1=$(( $digits + 1 ));      #digits + 1
        local tval="${value:0:$digits_1}"; #leading digits, plus one
        tval=$(( $tval + 5 ));          #half-add
        local tlength=${#tval};         #check if carried a digit
        local zerox="";
        if (( tlength > length )); then
            zerox="0";
        fi
        value="${tval:0:$digits}${zeros:0:$((length-$digits))}$zerox";
    fi  

    echo "$value";
}
```

See how this can be done much shorter, but that's another exercise for the student.

Avoiding floating point math due to the [inherit problems within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error?s=2|3.9455).

All sorts of special cases, like negative numbers, are not covered.

Comment: Instead of `zeros="$( eval "printf...`, you can use `printf -v zeros` to achieve the same effect.