# Self-written search algorithm not working as desired

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, search

I've written an algorithm that given a set of 2-D co-ordinates,generates the shortest path to traverse a building given that there are certain prohibited points, i.e., the points where the building is present.

I create a list of these points by using a nested while loops and incrementing between the boundaries by 0.01.

I also then remove these points from a set of potential neighbors that is generated while trying to figure out the next best point to go to.

The heuristic I'm using is to minimize the sum of the distances of the potential point to the start and to the goal.

I have 4 different goals (nodes) and iterate through them and changing the starting points for that iteration when needed.

In spite of this, there are some points being included in the end result that are located where the building is supposed to be, essentially making this a non-viable path.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import math
import copy

def distance(point1, point2):
    '''
    Computers distance between two points, two dimensional for now
    '''
    dist = math.sqrt(math.pow(point1[0] - point2[0], 2) + math.pow(point1[1] - point2[1], 2))
    return dist


def check(point1, point2):
    '''
    Checks if they are the same point or not
    '''
    for i in range(len(point1)):
        if round(point1[i], 1) != round(point2[i], 1):
            return False
    return True


def round_point(point):
    '''
    Rounds all the 2 co-ordinates of a point
    '''
    for i in range(len(point)):
        for j in range(len(point[i])):
            point[i][j] = round(point[i][j], 2)
    return point


def check_in(points, prohibited, visited):
    '''
    Removes all prohibited points from points and returns
    '''
    points = round_point(points)
    temp = copy.deepcopy(points)
    for i in range(len(points)):
        if points[i] in prohibited:
            #print('b')
            temp.remove(points[i])
        elif len(visited) != 0:
            if points[i] in visited:
                #print('c')
                temp.remove(points[i])
    return temp
    

def heuristic(points, start, destination):
    '''
    Calculates heuristic for each point
    '''
    l = []
    for i in range(len(points)):
        dist = distance(start, points[i]) + distance(destination, points[i])
        l.append(dist)
    return l


def neighbours(point):
    '''
    Finds all the points at a distance of 0.1m from the given point
    '''
    points = []
    for i in range(360):
        y = point[1] + 0.1 * math.sin((i * 2 * math.pi) / 180)
        x = point[0] + 0.1 * math.cos((i * 2 * math.pi) / 180)
        points.append([x, y])
    return points


def best(points, prohibited, start, end, visited):
    '''
    Chooses the point which is least distance that is not prohibited
    '''
    points = check_in(points, prohibited, visited)
    distances = heuristic(points, start, end)
    loc = distances.index(min(distances))
    return points[loc]


def search():
    '''
    Main function that searches
    '''
    nodes = [[2.5, 1.5], [2.5, 8.5], [7.5, 1.5], [7.5, 8.5]]
    # Creates a list of prohibited points
    prohibited = []
    x = 2.5
    y = 1.5
    visited = []
    while x <= 7.5:
        while y <= 8.5:
            prohibited.append([x, y])
            y += 0.01
        x += 0.01
    # Path to be traversed
    path = []
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        if i == 0:
            # Start has to be origin for first iteration
            start = [0, 0]
        else:
            start = nodes[i - 1]
        destination = nodes[i]
        # Calculates points for first iteration
        points = neighbours(start)
        loc = best(points, prohibited, start, destination, visited)
        path.append(loc)
        visited.append(loc)
        while True:
            # If the current location is the destination, loop is done
            if check(loc, destination):                break
            else:
                points = neighbours(loc)
                loc = best(points, prohibited, start, destination, visited)
                path.append(loc)
                visited.append(loc)
        continue
    return path   

path = search()
print(path)
print(len(path))
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the source of your problem, but your notion of point equality is not transitive. If `check(p1,p2)` and `check(p2,p3)` are both true, it doesn't follow that `check(p1,p3)` is. Why use floats for coordinates? You could think of it as a discrete grid of points which are indexed by integers.

Comment: I need to use floating point values as the simulator I plan to implement this in has continuous coordinates, i.e., floats. I tried to overcome this by rounding to two decimal places

Comment: @SuhasThalanki You can always convert your internal grid coordinates to floating point values appropriate for drawing when used in the simulator. Using floating point numbers you have to deal with [floating point error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python).

Comment: @NathanS. but then the distance between any two points will be 1m at the lowest. Won't floating point error be mitigated when I'm rounding it to two decimal places?

Comment: @SuhasThalanki Rounding to two places has no impact. See [the examples in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error).