# Why do I get different results when I use predict with all history and in real time using keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I wanna use predictions in real time, but I want to test that the results are the same as in the case of giving all the data as input only once. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, SimpleRNN
from keras.models import Model

#MODEL 1, for training
x = Input(shape=(None, 1))
h = SimpleRNN(30, return_sequences=True)(x)
out = Dense(1)(h)
model = Model(x, out)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

X_train = np.random.rand(100, 50, 1)
y_train = np.random.rand(100, 50, 1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose = False)

#MODEL 1, for predictions in real time
x = Input(batch_shape=(1, None, 1))
h = SimpleRNN(30, stateful=True, return_sequences=True)(x)
out = Dense(1)(h)
predict_model = Model(x, out)
predict_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())

X = np.random.rand(2, 2, 1)
predictions = model.predict(X, verbose = False)
for sim in range(len(predictions)):
    for i in range(len(predictions[0])):
        pred = predict_model.predict(X[sim:(sim+1), i:(i + 1), :], verbose = False)
        print(pred[0][0]) #Predictions in real time
        print(predictions[sim][i]) #Predictions with MODEL 1
        print()
    predict_model.reset_states()
```

It prints this:

`[0.09156141]`

`[0.09156139]`

`[-0.38076958]`

`[-0.38076955]`

`[0.12214336]`

`[0.12214339]`

`[-0.52013564]`

`[-0.5201356]`

The results must be exactly the same because both have the same weights. What is happening?

Comment: It may be a floating point error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error

Comment: But in case the error is due to possible floating point values, the values of both predictions should be rounded to the same value.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. It's possibily a part of randomness in the SimpleRNN Keras model then ?

Comment: You could restart your program to check if the result are differents from the previous one or not

Comment: Once the model is trained, randomness does not intervene.

Comment: Yes, if I restart the program i get different results because the input changes (i am not using the same seed). But the problem persists. Sometimes both values match

Comment: I have tested the code with the same code and the problem persists.
If I write this: 
import tensorflow as tf
np.random.seed(0)
tf.random.set_seed(0)

I always get this:
[0.09520281]
[0.09520283]

[0.33807808]
[0.33807802]

[0.0579582]
[0.05795821]

[0.18572299]
[0.18572299]

Comment: Right. I think there are layers that include a part of randomness such as a dropout layer that will make prediction have differents result from the same model but in your case I don't think that's due to a dropout layer. (there aren't dropout layer in the SimpleRNN by default)